# I am having a "The file could not be written to disk." error in ExpressionEngine with files 2MB and up

Tags: amazon-web-services, expressionengine

Has anyone had this issue where they are getting a The file could not be written to disk. error on ExpressionEngine v2.9.2. I notice I am only having this issue with files 2MB and up and in following other posts I have turned off XSS filtering with no help. If it means anything I have EE running on two EC2 instances that are being load balanced. Deployments are handled with OpsWorks. I have also increased file upload size and post size, as well as the ELB connection settings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I found the issue. AWS uses some sort of virtual `/tmp` directory by default. So I used the command `df -h` which showed me that my "overflow `/tmp`" directory was only 1M which is what caused the could not be written to disk error. After searching how to fix that I found that you could use `sudo umount -l /tmp` to unmount the current directory and then use `sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=10485760,mode=1777 overflow /tmp` to make that directory 10M.

Comment: Beat me to posting. :) For posterity, that error is directly linked to PHP's `UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE` error (http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php), so typical causes are lacking room on the disk, or no write access to `/tmp`.