# Laravel 5.1 files larger than 1mb not uploading

Tags: php, laravel

I've a site and CMS built on top of Laravel 5.1. The file images larger than 1mb are not being uploaded and gives me Error 500.
But when I scale down the same image to 200kb or 400kb, it uploads without any issues.
I've also updated the php.ini settings for
upload_max_filesize = 70M, post_max_size = 100M and memory_limit = 32M

Comment: What is the error you get with the 500?

Comment: please check your server log,to get this error message.

Comment: enable error reporting and paste error code `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 'on');`

Comment: Ok guys, here it is, this is from my error_log file :
[11-Apr-2016 07:39:09 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 11264 bytes) in /home/AAAAA/public_html/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/Gd/Decoder.php on line 34

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increase the memory limit to 64 MB or 128 MB from php.ini. I hope it will work for you.

And you can see laravel error at storage/logs/laravel.log.

Comment: Thanks ahossain for your help. I increased this to 128MB and it worked plus I also increased the timeout variables as well.

Comment: @UsmanMahmood if any answer seems right to you then make it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I updated `memory_limit`, `post_max_size`, `max_execution_time` etc.. but the problem was still persisting.

This answer resolved my issue: [I am having a "The file could not be written to disk." error in ExpressionEngine with files 2MB and up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34618271/i-am-having-a-the-file-could-not-be-written-to-disk-error-in-expressionengine/34619685#34619685)

The issue was that the /tmp mount was only 1MB. Running command df -h will determine the size of your mount.

I had to unmount the /tmp by running command: `sudo umount -l /tmp`.

Than remounted it with 16MB by running command: `sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=16485760,mode=1777 overflow /tmp`.

Comment: Link are great but to have a good answer you should write in the post itself what in this link was helpful to solve the  problem. Thank you.
See [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) section about links